# Background is half black until I click a link

Tags: javascript, iframe

On my website, we are tracking a ship (http://marineops.mlml.calstate.edu/ptsur1) and now the the ship has gotten further away from port, a black background appears.  The only way I know to fix it is to click a link in the popup window that describes the ship (the link is "Show Vessel's Track Distance...".  After that, I cannot remove the popup window.

It is a drupal 6 site and code that creates the map is  (I got this code from http://marinetraffic.com/ais/addyourarea.aspx?level1=150 under "Put a Live map of your area in your website):

**If background is black, click "Show Vessel's Track Distance..."**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        width='100%';           //the width of the embedded map in pixels or percentage
        height=400;             //the height of the embedded map in pixels or percentage
        border=1;               //the width of border around the map. Zero means no border
        notation=false;         //true or false to display or not the vessel icons and options at the left
        shownames=true;         //true or false to dispaly ship names on the map
        latitude=36.676;        //the latitude of the center of the map in decimal degrees
        longitude=-124.405;     //the longitude of the center of the map in decimal degrees
        zoom=12;                //the zoom level of the map. Use values between 2 and 17
        maptype=2;              //use 0 for Normal map, 1 for Satellite, 2 for Hybrid, 3 for Terrain
        trackvessel=366974890;  //the MMSI of the vessel to track, if within the range of the system
        fleet='';               //the registered email address of a user-defined fleet to display
        remember=false;         //true or false to remember or not the last position of the map
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.marinetraffic.com/ais/embed.js"></script>
```

Please visit the website   http://marineops.mlml.calstate.edu   and offer any suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: To me it looks like google has no image data on your zoom level. If you zoom out there is image, and if you choose to display the map instead of sattelite too... Has nothing to do with marinetraffic of drupal.